# How do I match UILabel's font with another one that has adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth enabled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uilabel

I have two `UILabels`. One of them has the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` enabled. How do I copy over the font to another `UIlabel`?

```
UILabel *labelLong = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
labelLong.text = @"Very very long text";
labelLong.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;

UILabel *labelShort = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 50, 50)];
labelShort.text = @"LOL";
```

Just copying over the font from the other label does not seem to work:

```
labelShort.font = labelLong.font
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, if you log the font of labelLong, it still shows it as the default size of 17, so you can't do this the simple way. One way I found to do it, was to start with the original font, and loop through smaller font sizes until the text's bounding rect's width is smaller than the labels text rect's width (as gotten from textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:). This code worked for me, but I haven't tested it thoroughly. I adjust the font size by 0.1 each time through the loop to get a reasonably accurate answer.

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *labelLong;
@property (strong,nonatomic) UILabel *labelShort;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.labelLong = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 50, 50, 50)];
    self.labelLong.text = @"Very text";
    self.labelLong.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.labelLong];

    self.labelShort = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 70, 50, 50)];
    self.labelShort.text = @"Very";
    [self.view addSubview:self.labelShort];
    [self updateFont];
}

-(void)updateFont {
    NSStringDrawingContext *ctx = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
    ctx.minimumScaleFactor = 1.0;
    UIFont *startingFont = self.labelLong.font;
    NSString *fontName = startingFont.fontName;
    CGFloat startingSize = startingFont.pointSize;
    for (float i=startingSize*10; i>1; i--) {
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:i/10];
        CGRect textRect = [self.labelLong.text boundingRectWithSize:self.labelLong.frame.size options:NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:ctx];
        if (textRect.size.width < [self.labelLong textRectForBounds:self.labelLong.bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:1].size.width) {
            NSLog(@"Font size is: %f", i/10);
            NSLog(@"Font rect is: %@",NSStringFromCGRect(textRect));
            self.labelShort.font = [UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:i/10];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ugh, I had a feeling that I'd end up doing something like this. Is there any reason why the font size isn't updated when I set the property?

Comment: @EnricoSusatyo, no, I don't know what Apple is doing in this method, whether they actually change the font, or just scale it down somehow.

Answer (score 0):

After getting the font name and font size of the longlabel, we can assign them to another label.
You can try like this,

```
NSString *fName = self.labelLong.font.fontName;
CGFloat fSize = self.labelLong.font.pointSize;
[labelShort setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fName size:fSize]];
```

Comment: I've just tried this, it doesn't seem to work for me. How would this be different than just `labelShort.font = labelLong.font`?